# Assign task to user, then assign task to all users in group minus that user

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, task-list

Is there a way to assign a task or email a group of people, but restrict which users in that group get the task or email?

I have a requirement for an approval workflow that is to initially be approved by the user's immediate manager, then by all managers. I can achieve this in the workflow, but I am looking for a solution that does not require the workflow to be edited when managers/roles change.

Groups came to mind to be assigned the second task, but then the original approver would be assigned a duplicate task since they also reside in that group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using tasks. Instead users are sent requests by group and through REST I can manage specifically which users in that group will be assigned a task.